# Pycharm inspection not flagging unresolved references in classes inherited from a stubbed object

Tags: pycharm, pyside2

I'm doing a lot of PySide2 development in PyCharm (Professional 2020.3).

I have the stub files for PySide2 installed, which gives me quite good auto-completion, but somehow it doesn't detect unresolved references on some rather obvious cases.

See this screenshot:

[image]

When inheriting from any class that has an actual python definition, everything is fine, but when the parent class comes from a stub (pyi) file, it doesn't seem to detect that the reference is unresolved. Nowhere in the stub file self.missing is defined (and it happens with any name).

I have searched online for a while but all I can find are people complaining about pycharm flagging too many things as missing references, wherein this case it doesn't flag enough.

Are there special settings to set somewhere? Is it a subtlety of pyi files that need to be written differently? Or maybe a PyCharm bug?

Comment: Does QWidget or any of StubbedTest ancestors have `__getattr__` function defined?

Comment: Yes, one of the parent classes has: def __getattr__(self, name: str) -> typing.Any: ...

Comment: That's the cause. Since `__getattr__` can provide additional attributes, PyCharm disables unresolved references checks in this case.

Comment: I've commented that in the stub files, I'll see if that does it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As hinted by user2235698 in the comments, one of the stub objects (QObject) had reimplemented `__getattr__`, which caused Pycharm to accept any attribute as correct.

Removing this line from the .pyi file sorted the issues.